# Adding values in database with query in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to add 10 from a current database value. 
Current db value = 20;adding = 10;updated value 30;
The following code is not working.
`DB::table('employee')->increment('bonus'=>'bonus+10');`

Comment: try this: Employee::find($employee_id)->increment('bonus', 10);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DB::table('employee')->increment('bonus', 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
DB::table('employee')->increment('bonus', 10);
```

You can do like this as well:

```
DB::table('employee')
   ->where('rowID', 1) // if you to add in a perticular table else comment it for updating entire column's value by adding 10 in it.
   ->update([
       'bonus' => DB::raw('bonus + 10'),
   ]);
```

Hope this will help you.